Run ubuntu desktop app using terminal on server
I need to run an app (is a 2d cad vector app) on Ubuntu using terminal. I’m not an expert on Linux so I try to explain better and sorry if i don’t use the right terms.
I installed Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS. This app can run using GUI or can be a “server” that listens on a specified IP and port for commands. Giving commands instruction, the app executes specific actions emulating actions that normally are performed with a mouse. I run this command to pass in terminal version:
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target

Now that I’m in terminal version, I run my app using this command:
xvfb-run myapp
Using xvfb, everything works perfectly and as expected. How can I run the xvfb command at boot? I tried using a script on boot, but it gives me problem on the functionality of the app. I don’t know why if use a script the app don’t work properly. What is the best way to do it?

You mention that it gives me problem on the functionality of the app. Could you provide relative errors or logs? Please edit your question to have the new info.

Unfortunately no logs are available. The only information that I have is that if I run the command on terminal it works, but if I use a script it won’t work. I’m not sure if I’m running the script in right way or if there is a proper way to run it.
